# Prove that if $f$ is zero at two points, then it is zero over the interval between them

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Suppose $f$ satisfies $f''(x) + f'(x)g(x) - f(x) = 0$ for some function $g$. Prove that if $f$ is zero at two points, then it is zero over the interval between them.

Let's suppose that $f(a) = f(b) = 0$ where $a<b$. Then using Rolles theorem, we know that there exists a $c$ such that $f'(c) = 0$ on $[a,b]$. Therefore, $f''(c) = f(c)$. Then how do I show that $f(x)=0$ on $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose we have $a < \xi < b$, with $f(a)=f(b)=0$ and $f(\xi) \ne 0$. We may assume that $f(\xi) > 0$ (otherwise we can just replace $f$ by $-f$). So $f$ attains a maximum at some point $\eta \in (a,b)$. And at this maximum:

- what is the sign of $f''(\eta)$?
- what is the value of $f'(\eta)$?
- why does this lead to a contradiction?